# Excel VBA how to find the next value once the first is matched

Tags: excel, vba

My code below will show all the record found from the call number, but as I have duplicate call numbers. For example: 389905 has two records in excel. I want to click on the search button to bring up the next match call number with its record.

Is this possible ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

row_number = 1
Do
    DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    item_in_review = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & row_number)
    If item_in_review = txtCall.Text Then
        txtLogged.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & row_number)
        txtName.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("C" & row_number)
        txtSite.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & row_number)
        txtType.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("E" & row_number)
        txtTitle.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("F" & row_number)
        cmbOwner.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("G" & row_number)
        cmbResponder.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("H" & row_number)
        txtReference.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("I" & row_number)
    End If
Loop Until item_in_review = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Find` and `FindNext` rather than looping through the data.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: How would I write the code out? Can you show me?

Comment: Is it the case you have a `UserForm` to show the values of the record, but the problem is that you only ever see the *last* record for 389905 ? I take it you want to be able to review the values for multiple entries of 389905  ?

Comment: Yes that's absolutely correct. It shows the last record instead of showing both, when I press the search button twice. I ideally want a next button or to click on the search button twice to show both records.

Comment: Does someone know the code on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a class to hold each set of values:

Create a class module and name it `clsCallDetails`.
Add this code to the module:

```
Option Explicit

'Class module named 'ClsCallDetails'

Private pLogged As String
Private pName As String
Private pSite As String
Private pCallType As String
Private pOwner As String
Private pResponder As String
Private pReference As String

Public Property Get Logged() As String
    Logged = pLogged
End Property
Public Property Let Logged(Value As String)
    pLogged = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Site() As String
    Site = pSite
End Property
Public Property Let Site(Value As String)
    pSite = Value
End Property

Public Property Get CallType() As String
    CallType = pCallType
End Property
Public Property Let CallType(Value As String)
    pCallType = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Owner() As String
    Owner = pOwner
End Property
Public Property Let Owner(Value As String)
    pOwner = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Responder() As String
    Responder = pResponder
End Property
Public Property Let Responder(Value As String)
    pResponder = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Reference() As String
    Reference = pReference
End Property
Public Property Let Reference(Value As String)
    pReference = Value
End Property
```

Create a normal module and add this code to it:
**Edit:** Originally had `Find_CallNumbers` as a function; have changed it to a sub.

```
Option Explicit

'Normal Module

Public CallDetails As Collection

Public Sub Find_CallNumbers(NumberToFind As String)

    Dim rng_to_search As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim FoundItem As clsCallDetails

    Set CallDetails = New Collection

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
        Set rng_to_search = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With rng_to_search
        'Look for the first instance.
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=NumberToFind, _
                           After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                Set FoundItem = New clsCallDetails 'Create a new instance of the class to hold the details.
                With FoundItem
                    .Logged = rFound.Offset(, 1) 'Offset from column A by 1 column, so column B.
                    .Name = rFound.Offset(, 2)
                    .Site = rFound.Offset(, 3)
                    .CallType = rFound.Offset(, 4)
                    .Owner = rFound.Offset(, 5)
                    .Responder = rFound.Offset(, 6)
                    .Reference = rFound.Offset(, 7)
                End With
                CallDetails.Add FoundItem 'Add the class instance to our collection.
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound) 'Look for the next value.

            'Continue searching until we reach the top again.
            Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Create a form containing these controls (I've put the control names above the controls):
[image]

Add this code to the form:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
    Find_CallNumbers Me.txtSearchNumber
    Me.txtCurrentIndex = 1
    PlaceValues (Me.txtCurrentIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub PlaceValues(Index As Long)
    With Me
        .txtLogged.Value = Format(CallDetails(Index).Logged, "HH:MM:SS")
        .txtName.Value = CallDetails(Index).Name
        '... 
        '...
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    Me.txtCurrentIndex = Me.txtCurrentIndex + 1
    PlaceValues (Me.txtCurrentIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click()
    Me.txtCurrentIndex = Me.txtCurrentIndex - 1
    PlaceValues (Me.txtCurrentIndex)
End Sub
```

When you search for a number it will find and display the details of the first found item.  Clicking Next/Previous will take you to the next instance.
You'll need to add error checking - such as when it reaches the end or beginning of the collection, or if the searched number isn't found.

Comment: Thank you. I have a small issue. It works then it doesn't work. I get an error. Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure call or aurgument. Its calling at this line. .txtLogged.Value = Format(CallDetails(Index).Logged, "HH:MM:SS")

Comment: Does `CallDetails(Index).Logged` have a value?  If it does - is a numeric value (probably less than 1)? Have you named the **textbox control** on the form `txtLogged`?  Is the code in the Userform so that it can make use of the `Me` keyword?

Comment: The txtLogged textbox will be the name of the person who logged the call in. so its someone name for example Julia Chan. Yes I know it doesn't explain well. Yes the textbox control is named txtLogged

Comment: Try `.txtLogged.Value = CallDetails(Index).Logged` (I thought it was the time the call was logged, so formatted as time).

Comment: Say if I also wanted to search by email. How would I go about searching through multiple records via a persons email. Can you help?? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to update where `rng_to_search` is set so it looks at the email column (update each of the `Cells` values to look at the correct column number - currently looks at column 1).  The `NumberToFind` argument will still work, but maybe update it to `ValueToFind`.